# Assign ng-model an object in a select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-init

I'm iterating over a range and populating new select options for each index. The options are not related to the range I am iterating over but are options of different types. Code as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in range(booking.numberOfRooms) track by $index">
    <p>Room {{$index + 1}}</p>
    <select ng-model="booking.roomSelection[$index]" ng-options="obj.roomType as obj.roomType for obj in roomTypes" ng-init="booking.roomSelection[$index] = { id: $index + 1, roomType: 'Double' }"> </select>
</div>
```

How can I assign an object array to ng-model (Like that in ng-init)? E.g. For two rooms, the result of ng-model should look something like:

```
booking.roomSelection = [{id: 1, roomSelection: 'Double'}, {id: 2, roomSelection: 'Double'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the ng-model attribute had to be changed to: `booking.roomSelection[$index].roomType`

The object array must also be declared in the controller, e.g. `$scope.booking.roomSelection = [];`

The full declaration being:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in range(booking.numberOfRooms) track by $index">
    <p>Room {{$index + 1}}</p>
    <select ng-model="booking.roomSelection[$index].roomType" ng-options="obj.roomType as obj.roomType for obj in roomTypes" ng-init="booking.roomSelection[$index] = { id: $index + 1, roomType: 'Double' }"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `ng-model="booking.roomSelection[$index]"` if `ng-options="obj as obj.roomType for obj in roomTypes"`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind to your `booking.roomSelection` and remove the `ng-init`.If you will select two options, their value will be `pushed` into the `booking.roomSelection` and `booking.roomSelection` will be an array

```
<select multiple ng-model="booking.roomSelection" ng-options="obj.roomType as obj.roomType for obj in roomTypes"></select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not push to the ng-model, it only assigns the value of the selection which gets overwritten with the value of the selected option. I.e. book.roomSelection will only ever be a single value.

Comment: @ImranNZ You want to select 2 options and get their values in the `booking.roomSelection`, yes?

Comment: Add the `multiple` attribute on the select

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Suren, I should have made it clear. I have a new drop box for each room (Not a multiple select).